# Can deepstream sdk work on GTX Geforce nvidia graphic cards?

Tags: nvidia-deepstream

I have an old geforce GTX (960 M) graphic card , and i wanted to use the Deep-stream SDK , does it support older generation graphic cards ?

Comment: The docs says dGPU (“discrete GPU”) to refer to NVIDIA GPU expansion card products such as NVIDIA® Tesla® T4 and P4, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1080, and NVIDIA® GeForce® RTX 2080:  [https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/dev-guide/index.html#page/DeepStream_Development_Guide/deepstream_quick_start.html] but it doesn't says if it works anyway maybe not GPU accelerated

Comment: I couldnt seem to set it up on my system, so i got a jetson nano instead and its supports it